# get programmatically notified when processing is over

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

When uploading video to YouTube, the resulting video link becomes immediately available, but the video is not yet ready to be played, because Youtube is processing it. How to get programmatically notified upon the completion of the processing? I am using node.js googleapis.

Answer (score 0):

`/youtube/videos/list` provides the API to query the video upload status.

```
var videoId = 'aBcdEfjhkLm'

const Youtube = require("youtube-api"), fs = require("fs"),
    readJson = require("r-json"), Lien = require("lien"),
    Logger = require("bug-killer"), opn = require("opn"),
    prettyBytes = require("pretty-bytes");

const CREDENTIALS = readJson(`${__dirname}/credentials.json`);
let server = new Lien({ host: "localhost" , port: 5000 });
let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth", client_id: CREDENTIALS.web.client_id,
    client_secret: CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret,
    redirect_url: CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
});

opn(oauth.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline", scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]
}));

server.addPage("/oauth2callback", lien => {
    Logger.log("code: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {
        if (err) { lien.lien(err, 400); return Logger.log(err); }
        Logger.log("Got the tokens.");
        oauth.setCredentials(tokens);
        lien.end(
        '<script>window.close()</script>'

        );
        var req = Youtube.videos.list({
            id: 'fEJc2CwddgU',
            part: "status",
        },
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err:', err)
                process.exit()
            }
            var s = data.items[0].status.uploadStatus
            if (s == 'uploaded') console.log('Video is being processed.')
            if (s == 'processed') console.log('Video processing completed.')
            process.exit()
        });
    });
});
```